# Derivation of general binding equation (macromolecule with multiple binding sites)

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, enzyme-kinetics

So the last days I'm stuck at trying to solve the an equation - but I just can't (see the screenshot below.
[image]

So the idea is that you have a receptor or enzyme with multiple binding sites for a Ligand (let's assume 3 binding sites). They are not influencing each other and have the same affinity.
The equations above show how the microscopic dissociation constants are related to the microscopic dissociation constants and that the same "affinity" of a binding site does not relate to a similar macroscopic dissociation constant for each subsequent binding step.

However, I just cannot see how they get from here
[image]

to here

[image]

I already tried to solve the calculations in every way I could think of. ChatGPT fails miserably. Also I didn't find any other sources...

Is somebody able to solve it? Or knows a paper/source that solved this step by step? I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{_AE^A}$ is in equilibrium with $\ce{E}$ and $\ce{A}$ along two paths:

$$\ce{E + 2A <=> E^A + A <=> _AE^A}$$

and

$$\ce{E + 2A <=> _AE + A <=> _AE^A}.$$

So you get the equivalence:

$$[\ce{_AE^A}] = \frac{[\ce{E^A}] [\ce{A}]}{K^{12}} = \frac{[\ce{_AE}] [\ce{A}]}{K^{21}}$$

With these kinds of relationships, you can simplify the expression, cancel all the concentration terms and get the result in the book (after getting rid of fractions by multiplying with the equilibrium constants in the denominators). The math is elementary yet tedious.

$$K_2' = \frac{\ce{([E^A] + [_AE] + [E_A])[A]}}{\ce{[_AE^A] + [E_A^A] +  [_AE_A]}}  \tag{1}$$

$$= \frac{\ce{([E^A] + [_AE] + [E_A])[A]}}{\frac{[\ce{E^A}] [\ce{A}]}{K^{12}} + \frac{[\ce{E^A}] [\ce{A}]}{K^{13}} + \frac{[\ce{_AE}] [\ce{A}]}{K^{23}} }\tag{2}$$

$$= \frac{\ce{[E^A] + [_AE] + [E_A]}}{\frac{[\ce{E^A}]}{K^{12}} + \frac{[\ce{E^A}]}{K^{13}} + \frac{[\ce{_AE}] }{K^{23}} }\tag{3}$$

$$= \frac{K^{12} K^{13} K^{23}(\ce{[E^A] + [_AE] + [E_A]})}{K^{13} K^{23} [\ce{E^A}] + K^{12} K^{23}[\ce{E^A}] + K^{12} K^{13} [\ce{_AE}]}\tag{4}$$

$$= \frac{K^{12} K^{13} K^{23}(\ce{[E^A] + \frac{K^{21}}{K^{12}}[E^A] + \frac{K^{31}}{K^{13}}[E^A]})}{K^{13} K^{23} [\ce{E^A}] + K^{12} K^{23}[\ce{E^A}] + K^{21} K^{13} [\ce{E^A}]}\tag{5}$$

$$= \frac{K^{12} K^{13} K^{23}(\ce{1 + \frac{K^{21}}{K^{12}} + \frac{K^{31}}{K^{13}}})}{K^{13} K^{23} + K^{12} K^{23} + K^{21} K^{13} }\tag{6}$$

$$= \frac{K^{12} K^{13} K^{23} + K^{21} K^{13} K^{23} + K^{12} K^{31} K^{23}}{K^{13} K^{23} + K^{12} K^{23} + K^{21} K^{13} }\tag{7}$$

This is slightly different from the textbook, maybe a typo or a different interpretation of the subscripts. Exercise for the reader...

If you consider the following sequence:

$$\ce{ _AE^A <=>  E^A + A <=> E_A^A <=> E_A + A <=> _AE_A <=> _AE + A <=> _AE^A}$$

you find that the equilibrium constants are not all independent, as

$$ K^{13} K^{32} K^{21} = K^{12} K^{31} K^{23},$$

so there are multiple ways to write this result.

On a different note, if you say the binding sites are equivalent and independent, you can quickly relate apparent and individual binding constants. For the first binding event, you go from one state (all sites empty) to three (one site occupied), hence the factor 3. For the second binding event, you go from three states (one site occupied) to three states (one site empty), so the factor is 1. For the third binding event, you go from three states (one site empty) to one state (all sites occupied), so the factor is 1/3.

Comment: Instead of eternal gratitude, I'd be satisfied with a simple check mark if it pleases the OP.

Comment: I think I spotted the mistake in my calculations. I counted the concentrations twice. A ligand bound to enzyme at position 1 and 2 compared to 2 and 1 results in the same product, therefore they should be set equal, not add them up. Thanks a lot for helping out. 
I know it makes intuitively sense, yet, in order to derive the Higgs equation later, I thought it might be important to understand the maths properly. 
You shall have my gratitude and a check mark :)

Comment: Just a follow up question, since I still cannot get it right.
Apparantly its wrong to assume that EA2 = EA2(1,2) + E2(1,3) + E2(2,1) + E2(2,3) + E2(3,1) + E2(3,2). Because If I formulate the relation you described (e.g., E2(1,2) = E1*A/K1,2) and plug it into the equation and assume random numbers for it, then K2' = k2/2 and not K2' = k2. So I suppose because E2(1,2) = E2(2,1) I might count it twice. However, how should I plug in that EA2(1,2) = EA2(2,1)? If I set it equal as you described, there is no way to put it into the general equation K2' = ...

Comment: Yes, you are counting complexes twice. Putting a glove on your right hand first, then one on your left hand is the same as donning them in the opposite order. In fact, there should be a single symbol for that, not two symbols. On the other hand, it might be more comfortable to put on the left glove with the right hand already gloved than the opposite way, so there are two equilibrium constants for putting on the second glove.

Comment: I made my brain hurt adding the trivial math and ... arrived at an answer different from that of the textbook. For the case where all binding constants are equal, it does not make any difference, though.

Comment: Now you really have my eternal gratitude. I managed to solve it now and came to the same result as you have, which is almost the same as in the book. Maybe there are some alternative solutions, depending on which relations one uses to solve the equation... anyways, thanks for taking the time!

Comment: The 6 equilibrium constants describing going from one to two bound ligands are not independent. This means you could write the equation in different correct ways.